# Break a row into child and parent column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a large data set that I am working with in excel and I am wondering if it possible to do this in a more efficient way in excel.

For example, I have the a relationship row in excel. Every cell is a parent to the cell after it and a child to cell before it. I am trying to break each row in this row like the following. Any ideas ? I am not sure if excel is even capable of doing this.

```
Relationship row    X1  X2  X3  X4  X5

    Child Column    Parent Column   
        X1                X2        
        X2                X3        
        X3                X4        
        X4                X5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for Child Column:
`=IF(ROW($A1)<MAX(COLUMN($A$1:$E$1)),INDEX($A$1:$E$1,SMALL(COLUMN($A$1:$E$1),ROW($A1))),"")`
Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time
Your Data is in Row 1 and starting in A1
For Parent Column:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$E$1,SMALL(COLUMN($A$1:$E$1),ROW($A2))),"")`
Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time
And you can drag both formulas down to have all results

Answer (score 0):

If your Relationship Row is Row 1, starting in Column A, and your "Child Column" and "Parent Column" start in `A4` and `B4` respectively, you can use these formulas and drag down:

Child Column: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MAX(ROW()-3,1)))`
Parent Column: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MAX(ROW()-2,1)))`

[image]

And of course you can put say `=If([formula]=0,"",[formula])` to hide the `0` when there's no more info.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple formulas,

Child:

`=OFFSET($A$1,0,ROW(A1))`

Parent:

`=OFFSET($A$1,0,ROW(A2))`

[image]

Drag both of them throughout the range.